# Dynamically populated select showing old options in firebug, but correct options on the page

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I have a page for user data-entry that contains sections of rows of dynamic, dependent selects. I did not know something was amiss until I tried autoselecting the options for the user based on a delightful select2 that I just included in the page.  The dependent selects' correct options are showing on the page, BUT when I try to work with them in JQuery, only the old options are there.  Mysterious.  And I'm using Foundation 4 so it's adding some complexity. Here's a fiddle that works great, but my page is still broken: http://jsfiddle.net/jenborn/24Kpv/2/

When the page loads, here are the relevant selects:

```
<div class="small-3 columns">
   <select id="fer1_1" class="medium">
   <? echo $fer1_opt ?>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="small-3 columns">
   <select id="fer2_1" name="fer2_1" class="medium">
   <option>None selected</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Here is the function that is called when fer1_1 is changed:

```
function populateDep(){
     id_in_str = $(this).attr('id');
     var ctrl = id_in_str.slice(0,3); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
     var this_select = parseInt(id_in_str.slice(3,4), 10); // the second param is POSITION not LENGTH!
     var row = id_in_str.slice(5);

    $.getJSON("/cat_dropdowns.php",{parent_id: $(this).val(), required: '1', ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + j[i].value + '">' + j[i].text + '</option>';
      }

    var next_select = ++this_select;
      $("select#" + ctrl + next_select + "_" + row).html(options);
      Foundation.libs.forms.refresh_custom_select($('#' + ctrl + next_select + "_"  + row), true);
      Foundation.libs.forms.assemble();
    });
}
```

This code, right before attempting to set fer2_1's value reveals that it sees the old options:

```
 $("#" + prefix + "2_" + num + " > option").each(function() {
     console.log(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
 });
```

I see this in firebug: None selected

When I'm trying to auto-select fer2_1's value, I'm using this line (which I use successfully for fer1_1):

```
$("select#" + prefix + "2_" + num).val(smart_cat_data['cat_lvl3_id']);
```